# Adding in custom fonts and html to our email signatures

Tags: apex, trigger, email

The out of the box email signature in Salesforce is text based. Our organization has specific branding of colors and fonts that we want to include in all the emails we send out to our clients.

How can we implement our branded email signatures within all the emails our team sends out?

We also use the emailmessage object when sending out emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom HTML in a given user's personal email signature text box.

Something like the below:

[image]

```
<span style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: normal; color: #1f497d;">
Kind regards,
Kris Goncalves
</span>
```

will look like this in the email editor:

[image]

Salesforce also outlines in the following [document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327369&type=1&mode=1) an alternative without HTML to include the signature as an image in a Letterhead.

Comment: This is nice! I'd add that you can specify fallback fonts like this:
`font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`, that way should your email show up on different operating systems you can be sure that the style will be similar to what you hope for. Helvetica, for example, is an OSX font that is not included with Windows, but Arial is, and vice-versa. Including the "sans-serif" at the end will at the very least get you a sans-serif font on the end device.

Comment: Very good point. I had it initially then removed it to not add clutter/confusion just to prove the point (add custom font).